# spinner on form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I’m looking to build a script thats open a spinner on form submit or select change.

I’d like to use spin.js, (this is a working example from the developer):

```
var opts = {
  lines: 11, // The number of lines to draw
  length: 15, // The length of each line
  width: 10, // The line thickness
  radius: 30, // The radius of the inner circle
  corners: 1, // Corner roundness (0..1)
  rotate: 0, // The rotation offset
  direction: 1, // 1: clockwise, -1: counterclockwise
  color: '#000', // #rgb or #rrggbb
  speed: 0.6, // Rounds per second
  trail: 60, // Afterglow percentage
  shadow: false, // Whether to render a shadow
  hwaccel: false, // Whether to use hardware acceleration
  className: 'spinner', // The CSS class to assign to the spinner
  zIndex: 2e9, // The z-index (defaults to 2000000000)
  top: 'auto', // Top position relative to parent in px
  left: 'auto' // Left position relative to parent in px
};

var spinner = null;
var spinner_div = 0;

$(document).ready(function() {

  spinner_div = $('#spinner').get(0);

  $("#btn-spin").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if(spinner == null) {
      spinner = new Spinner(opts).spin(spinner_div);
    } else {
      spinner.spin(spinner_div);
    }
  });

 });
```

so.. when i click on my submit button

```
    <input id="btn-spin" type="submit" name="next" value="Continua" class="button-big"/>
```

or when i change a value on my select

```
                <select name="billing_country" onChange="this.form.submit();">
                    {billing_country_options}
                </select>
```

I’d like to:

1. add “lightbox-is-open” and “lightbox-is-fixed” classes to HTML
2. remove “hidden” class from my glasspane div
3. start (or show) the spinner
4. wait 500ms
5. submit the button or the select (and then other page will be loaded)

someone can help me please?
it’s too hard, a very difficult puzzle for me, (i’m a sound engineer, not a web developer)

thanks so much

Comment: 'add “lightbox-is-open” and “lightbox-is-fixed” classes to HTML' — to which element are you referring to?

Comment: I think nothing so relevant, just div elements for my css.. it should be something like ' $("html").toggleClass("lightbox-is-open"); '

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have initialized your spinner correctly, we can listen to either the form submit or select change events using jQuery, and avoid using inline JS. For your `<select>`, just remove the inline JS.

```
$(function() {
    // Remember to use 'var'
    var spinner_div = $('#spinner').get(0),
        spinner,
        opts = {
            // Opts go here
        },
        showSpinner = function() {
            // Add 'lightbox-is-open' and 'lightbox-is-fixed' classes to HTML
            $('html').addClass('lightbox-is-open lightbox-is-fixed');

            // Remove 'hidden' class from '.glasspane'
            $('.glasspane').removeClass('hidden');

            // Show spinner
            if(spinner == null) {
                spinner = new Spinner(opts).spin(spinner_div);
            } else {
                spinner.spin(spinner_div);
            }

            // Submit form after 500ms
            var timer = window.setTimeout(function() {
                $('form').submit();
            }, 500);
        };

    // Bind events
    $('form').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        showSpinner();
    });
    $('#btn-spin').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        showSpinner();
    });
    $('select').on('change', showSpinner);
});
```